Excel document how to remove time periods within a 30 minute interval of each other?
I'm not entirely sure how to explain this but here goes:
I have a dataset for a camera trap survey.
I have extracted all the image details to an excel document.
The column headings are: Source file, Date:time, species of animal, camera site, cam at site, image ID.
In essence there are multiple camera trap pictures from the same site, to create independence of images we need to remove all camera trap pictures from the same site (for each species) that occur within a 30 minute window. E.g. if there are 5 pics from site 12, at 12:01, 12:02, 12:03, 12:10, 13:55 I need to delete 3 of those records (12:02, 12:03, 12:10) retaining the 2 images that are classed as independent.
What function or formula can I use to do this? (apologies if I'm explaining this stupidly)
Checked a range of examples from previous questions but doesn't seem like anything answers this.
I think it got close with how to find objects within  a range, and I suppose that is a better phrase for what I want to achieve.
'how to delete time values within a 30 min range of each other'
Thanks!
Post-Comment EDIT:
hmmm still struggling to get my head around this, apologies. I attach a picture of a section of the data.
I'm not sure if formatting as a table links the data across all rows for when the formula is applied but I need to somehow maintain the data so it all corresponds.
Another level of complexity that I hadn't really considered is that it's not as easy as having 20 different times and removing those that occur within the 30min window -rather it has to be filtered by species of animal (lion, leopard, hyena etc) which is easy enough via the table option. However the painful thing is it also has to be done for each species and between each camera site (which I again assume can be done via table however would be so time consuming).
My brain is a little bit mushy at the moment, but hope that with a picture of the data may clarify things a bit (the first picture I literally copied the filtered lion data, selected each site from column H, then manually deleted each time stamp within a 30 min window) ... Second picture is the raw data. I would do it manually but there are like 60,000 records, so it's easy enough for some species but would otherwise take forever.
Sorry, and thanks again for the assistance.



It sounds a bit tricky. Suppose you had a previous reading at (say) 11:45 and adopted a simple strategy of starting at the beginning. You would end up deleting all of them except 11:45 and 13:55 and that might not be optimal. Or you  could divide the day up into 12-12:30, 12:30 to 13:00 etc. and get a different result.  Maybe give us a larger sample of data to show the bigger picture?

Keep One Time per Half Hour Interval


(SEQUENCE(48)-1)/48 is the time of a day split by half hour intervals i.e. 00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 1:30, ..., 23:30. A day has 48 half-hours. By starting with 0 and ending with 47, we will get the times to match against an exact match or next smaller (the -1 in the first match).
Always round decimal numbers before matching them.

Developing Mode
=LET(array,A2:A11,
    ra,ROUND(array,5),
    rd,ROUND((SEQUENCE(48)-1)/48,5),
    rm,XMATCH(ra,rd,-1),
    m,XMATCH(UNIQUE(rm),rm),
    r,INDEX(array,m),
    r)


Replace the bottom-most r with any other variable to see what it holds.

Final

After removing the redundant variables:

=LET(array,A2:A11,
    rm,XMATCH(ROUND(array,5),ROUND((SEQUENCE(48)-1)/48,5),-1),
    INDEX(array,XMATCH(UNIQUE(rm),rm)))


Taking the first scenario of just starting with the first one and checking the difference, you could use filter in a spill formula like this in Excel 365:
=LET(times,A2:A6,prev,VSTACK(-1,DROP(times,-1)),FILTER(times,times-prev>=TIME(0,30,0)))


Or more dynamic:
=LET(times,DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),prev,VSTACK(-1,DROP(times,-1)),
  FILTER(times,times-prev>=TIME(0,30,0)))

I think this reference is instructive.
Note
If you are using datetimes the comparisons become inaccurate.
I would change the formula to
=LET(times,A2:A6,prev,VSTACK(-1,DROP(times,-1)),FILTER(times,times-prev>TIME(0,29,59)))


I have tried the same method on more realistic data, using sort to group observations of the same species with the same camera together using sort, and sorting back into the original order at the end:
=LET(data,HSTACK(A2:C23,ROW(A2:C23)),
sdata,SORTBY(data,INDEX(data,,2),1,INDEX(data,,3),1,INDEX(data,,1),1),
include,MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),LAMBDA(I,IF(I=1,TRUE,(INDEX(sdata,I,2)<>INDEX(sdata,I-1,2))+(INDEX(sdata,I,3)<>INDEX(sdata,I-1,3))+(INDEX(   sdata,I,1)-INDEX(sdata,I-1,1))>TIME(0,29,59)))),
DROP(SORT(FILTER(sdata,include),4,1),,-1))



Yes, intuitively I would agree that some sort of sliding window approach would be better. But I'm just starting with the simplest approach and willing to develop further depending on feedback from OP and peers.

With VBA and a base time window.
Takes the first time as a base, delete the 30 min range and takes the next remained time as base
Sub camtime()
Dim col As Collection
Set col = New Collection
Set rg = Range("A13:A21")
mintime = rg(1)
For i = 2 To rg.Count
  If rg(i) - mintime < TimeValue("0:30") Then
    col.Add rg(i).Row
  Else
    mintime = rg(i)
  End If
Next i
For i = col.Count To 1 Step -1
  Rows(col(i)).Delete
Next i
End Sub




Excel's formula version of Black cat's VBA:
Formula in B2: =A2
Formula in B3:
=IFERROR(SCAN(B2, A3:A10, LAMBDA(current_time, dummy, XLOOKUP(current_time + 30 / 60 / 24, A3:A10, A3:A10, "", 1, 1))), "")

Basically, it is trying to use a dummy array in SCAN to get away with a recursive lambda.

